# Are photons electromagnetic waves, quantum waves, or both?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

Are photons [electromagnetic waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation), quantum waves, or both?

If I subdivide an electromagnetic field into smaller [electromagnetic fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_field), should I eventually find an electromagnetic wave of a [photon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon)?

How can individual quantum waves combine to form the macroscopic observable of an electromagnetic field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the wave-particle duality a real duality?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46237/)

Comment: A photon is a single excitation of an electromagnetic mode. So you can have photons of standing waves (see cavity QED), photons of free propagating modes, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are photons electromagnetic waves, quantum waves, or both?

A great ensemble of photons build up the electromagnetic wave.

> If I subdivide an electromagnetic field into smaller electromagnetic fields, should I eventually find an electromagnetic wave of a photon?

This experiment has been done with lasers bringing down to individual photon strength in this double slit experiment:

[image: photon double slit]

> The movie shows the diffraction of individual photon from a double slit recorded by a single photon imaging camera (image intensifier + CCD camera). The single particle events pile up to yield the familiar smooth diffraction pattern of light waves as more and more frames are superposed ([Recording by A. Weis](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/), University of Fribourg).

You ask:

> How can individual quantum waves combine to form the macroscopic observable of an electromagnetic field?

[It needs some strong math](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.htmltp://) background, but  handwaving:

Both the classical electromagnetic wave and the quantum photon rely on solutions of maxwell's equations. The individual photons carry information about the frequency  ( E=h*nu) and the spin and electromagnetic potential in the equation, since the quantum mechanical wavefunction of the photon ( which gives the probability distribution of the photon) and the classical wave depend on the same equations. There is a coherent synergy and the zillions of photons add up to give the classical wave.

Comment: I posted a similar question here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113632/photon-quantum-field-proportional-to-electromagnetic-field that you might be able to answer.

Comment: I had seen this answer before, but the link you provided for the math is privated, and it is not available in archive.org either..

Comment: @BlacklightMG  Unfortunately  it was made private. try this https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604169 . there are a number of papers with the photon wavefunction.